Why can't I update BIOS because keyboard isn't recognized in flash utility?
I want to update the BIOS of my Asus notebook F3JC from version 305 to 307 but when I try to update it using the AsusTek BIOS ROM Easy Flash Utility V1.10 it doesn't recognize all of the keyboard keys.
I even tried using another keyboard but only enter and escape work in both so I can't select the drive where the file is.

What can I do?

Have you tried putting the file in the directory that is shown in that screenshot? If you were to do that pressing enter should be enough. Are you plugging the keyboard in a USB 2 or USB 3 port?

@Ramhound How many laptops have an A: or B: nowadays?  This screen doesn't look like anything in the ASUS instructions for the update process..

@doneal24 - Tbe author has a 11 year old laptop. I would put money on it having only USB 2 and USB 3 ports.

I'm assuming there's a reason you can't use the windows based flash utility found here? https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/W2P/WinFlash_vista_070117.zip?model=F3JC
